# Flutter - Delaying json requests to do once per time

Tags: json, dart, flutter, delay

i'm trying to do a Dashboard with multiples jsons requests, but i want that request work one per one, like when finish first request start the second, when finish second start the third when finish third start the N.

my list code:

```
new CustomScrollView(
          cacheExtent: height * 6,
            slivers: [
              new SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      new RelatorioVendPeriodoAPeriodo(),
                      new RelatorioMensals(),
                      new RelatorioDiasDaSemanas(),
                      new RelatorioVendasTotalidasPorPeriodo(),
                      new RelatorioDasVendasTotsProdutos(),
                    ]
                  )
              )
            ]
        ),
```

this new classes calls, returns for me request. Anyone knows how to delay it?

Answer (score 0):

First, the parent widget should return a progress bar when the necessary data is not available.

A service will be called an initState to fetch data from the backend. when data is ready setState() will be called to redraw the widget.

Look at this example:

```
class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  var data;

  @override
  void initState() {
   data = NetworkService.getData().then((data) {
     setState(() {
       this.data = data;
     });
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (data == null) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      return
        new CustomScrollView(
            cacheExtent: height * 6,
            slivers: [
              new SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                      [
                        new RelatorioVendPeriodoAPeriodo(data: data),
                        new RelatorioMensals(data: data),
                        new RelatorioDiasDaSemanas(data: data),
                        new RelatorioVendasTotalidasPorPeriodo(data: data),
                        new RelatorioDasVendasTotsProdutos(data: data),
                      ]
                  )
              )
            ]
        );
  }
  }
}

class NetworkService {
  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

  static String data1;
  static String data2;

  static getData() async {
    if (data1 == null || data2 == null) {
      await fetchFromServer();
    }
    return {'data1': data1, 'data2': data2};
  }

  static fetchFromServer() async {
    data1 = (await http.get('url')).body;
    data2 = (await http.get('url')).body;
  }
}
```

Comment: But in this method, i need to load my jsons, but set their in the same variable "data"? i have different data in this classes.

Comment: You can use multiple variables for each of your data and you can save your jsons in these variables. your example is not complete. edit your question and put your whole code, then I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {

      print(" This line is executed after 5 seconds");

   });
```

Comment: 500 milliseconds are half a second, not 5 seconds.

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes that I shared an example of how to delay process time can increase.